# Why MAX method not found with my entity context

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I want to find Max number from a column, but i don't find Max( ) method with my Events class?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an extension method and you haven't included the `System.Linq` namespace.